# Automatically export file from a given software

Tags: csv, powershell, batch-file, automation, export

I have a folder with hundreds of files that were saved on a specific format of a given software (in this case it is the Qualisys Track Manager and the file format is .qtm).

This software has the option of **exporting** the files to another format such as TSV, MAT, C3D,...

My problem: I want to export all my files to TSV format but the only way I know is open the software, go to **File->Export->To TSV**. And doing this for hundreds of files is time consuming. So I was thinking on writing a script where I could call my files, access the software and it would do the export **automatically**.

But I have no clue how to do this, I was thinking on writing a script on Notepad++, running on the command window and then I would get all the files on TSV format.

[EDIT] After some research I think maybe a Batch script or a PowerShell script may help me but I have no idea how to run automatically the **commands of the software** of if it is even possible... (I am using Windows10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly likely to be a perpetual file format(.qtm) and Powershell/batch would not understand it. Unless this file can be read in a known way (Text XML etc), they would not be able to convert it.

I googled it and seems [QTM](http://www.qualisys.com/news/qualisys-track-manager-2-11-released/) have a REST API interface. It would be the best chance you have. I'm not sure if the documentation is available publicly, I didn't find it. I'd recommend you contact their support for REST API document/ask if their REST API can handle this task/sample code to get you start.

Then you can make REST API calls with [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) in a loop from powershell.